# Передача значения переменной между формами

Tags: c#, mysql

у меня есть две формы:

```
LoginForm
MainForm
```

На LoginForm я выполняю SQL-запрос, проверяющий наличие пользователя в базе данных и его ранг. При выполнение аутентификации открывает MainForm. Так вот получая, как мне записать значение строки Rang в переменную и передать в MainForm из LoginForm?

Пробовал создать Public переменную на форме LoginForm

```
public int isUserRang;
```

И записать в неё результат запроса:

```
db.openConnection();
isUserRang = (int)isUserRangCommand.ExecuteScalar();
db.closedConnection();
```

Но на форме MainForm эту переменную не видно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свой вопрос следующим образом. Создал класс

```
UserRang
```

В нем создал

```
public static string isUserRang;
```

И на форме MainForm обращался к нему.

Comment: Примите наиболее полезный ответ, поставьте галочку тогда.

Answer (score 2):

Несмотря на наличие ответов на подобные вопросы, думаю стоит дать некоторые кпояснения именно на этот вопрос.

Для начала определимся с терминами, т.к. из-за их неправильного употребления, очень часто следуют ошибки коде.

- **переменная**: именованная область памяти. В контексте языка C#, **переменные существуют только внутри методов**. У переменных не может быть никаких модификаторов т.к. они не являются самостоятельными сущностями. Если значение переменной необходимо передать за пределы метода, его нужно записать в поле или свойство какого-либо объекта или класса, либо вернуть с помощью инструкции return в качестве результата работы метода. Саму переменную нельзя никуда передать в принципе.
- **поле объекта**: именованная область памяти в блоке памяти, отведенном для хранения объекта. Поле, а точнее его значение, может быть передано вместе с самим объектом. Для доступа используется ссылка на объект и имя поля.
- **свойство объекта**: группа методов доступа к полям объекта, т.е. они не хранят значения, а только обеспечивают доступ к ним либо могут возвращать вычисляемые значения. Для работы также требуется ссылка на объект, свойства которого требуется получить.

Возвращаясь к вопросу, вы создали не переменную, а поле c модификатором public. В таком случае и обращаться к нему надо с помощью ссылки на объект формы логина, что-то вроде `myLoginForm.isUserRang`.

---

Не пренебрегайте правильным использованием терминов. Это избавляет от заметного количества проблем не только в программировании.

---

Д/з: разберитесь с терминами **поле класса** и **свойство класса** и чем они отличаются от описанных выше.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за ответ, сейчас почитаю про **поле класса** **свойства класса** и попробую обратиться по `myLoginForm.isUserRang`.